# merge many bytes arrays into one byte array in objective c

Tags: objective-c

i have Used `NSMutableData` to merge byte arrays

```
    NSMutableData *payload;
    payload = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

[payload appendBytes:CFBridgingRetain((cm.msgBytes)) length:[cm.msgBytes length]];

NSString *cmdata = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[payload mutableBytes] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

i want to keep on adding to `payload` until done

cmdata is always nil

as `initWithData` takes `NSData` so i converted the bytes to `NSData` but the result is still same

```
 NSData *bytesData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[payload mutableBytes] length:[payload length]];

 NSString *cmdata = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:bytesData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: The string is nil even after payload grows above zero length? Did you try using an NSMutableString?

Comment: yes the paylaod grows above zero and i can see the hex of the data , i have not used because the data in cm.msgBytes is byte array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're confusing things in several places. Where an API says "bytes", it's talking about a C array of bytes; where it says "data", it's talking about an `NSData` object.

Assuming `cm.msgBytes` is an `NSData` object, which it appears to be given that you retrieve its `.length`, a better version of this code would be:

```
NSMutableData *payload;
payload = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

[payload appendData:cm.msgBytes];

NSString *cmdata = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:payload encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

If you wrote the class `cm` belongs to, you should probably rename `msgBytes` to `msgData` (or even `messageData`), to match the APIs better.

Comment: well you are right , i was taking msgBytes as a c array when it was a NSData , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

initWithData takes an NSData not bytes itself

```
NSString *cmdata = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:payload encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: this also does not work 

NSData *bytesData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[payload mutableBytes] length:[payload length]];


NSString *cmdata = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:bytesData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];